# beforeedit and edit EXTJs

Tags: extjs

I am trying to pass a record from a `beforeedit` to a `edit` in EXT js in an editable grid, because I need to do a validation depending on the previous value of that field. For example I have the row (telephone number), when I tried to edit that field, I can do it only if telephone starts by 6, but if telephone starts by 9 I can only change it to another telephone that starts by 9.

I use the next in my code, but I dont know how can pass to the edit function the value before to edit. Here is my code:

```
   listeners: {

         beforeedit: {
             scope: this,
             fn: function(e, context2){
                 var record2= context2.record;
                 var recordData2=record2.getData();
                 alert(JSON.stringify(recordData2));
             }

         },

         edit: function(e, context){

             var record = context.record;
             var recordData = record.getData();
             recordData.Funcionalidad = 'Modificar';
             alert(JSON.stringify(recordData));
             Ext.Ajax.request({
                 url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                 method: 'POST',

                 // merge row data with other params
                 params: recordData


             });
         }
        }
```

How can I reference the previous value to the edit:function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
beforeedit: function(editor, e, eOpts) {
    var grid = Ext.getCmp('gridId'); // or e.grid
    if (e.record.data.phoneNumber === 'your condition') {
        //you code ..
        e.cancel = false; //may edit the record
    } else {
        e.cancel = true; //not allowed to edit
    }
},
```

Comment: i dont understand that piece of code, properly, because my program can allow changes to other values, not only allow or not allow, for example is my ESTLOT is 04 it can change to 05, but if the value is 06 it can change to 03 and 01